# What cross-game connectivity is there between Civilization: Beyond Earth and Starships?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth, starships

*[Sid Meier's Civilization: Beyond Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization:_Beyond_Earth)* and *[Sid Meier's Starships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sid_Meier's_Starships)* have some sort of cross-game connectivity. As I understand it, new features in either game can be unlocked in the other game by playing the games and connecting both to a [my2K account](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/201335163-my2K-Frequently-Asked-Questions). What are these unlockable features, and what is required to unlock them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two aspects to this question.

What Beyond Earth can unlock in Starships. Taken from [this wiki page](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Sid_Meier's_Starships). Note that the hybrid affinities are strictly better than their regular alternatives, and two hybrid pairs (e.g. Purity/Harmony and Harmony/Purity) have no functional differences.

> **Planet Type Unlocks** Winning a game of Civ:BE with each ending will unlock each of these.
>
> Planet Type - Nirvana: +5% Crew Morale (Unlocked by Harmony victory)
>
> Planet Type - Xanadu: +10% Science (Unlocked by Purity victory)
>
> Planet Type - Earth: +10% Metal (Unlocked by Supremacy victory)
>
> Planet Type - Observatory: Open Communications with all AI leaders (Unlocked by Contact Victory)
>
> **Hybrid Affinity Unlocks*** You need to reach Rank 7
>   of each main affinity and 3 of a second affinity to unlock the Hybrid
>   Affinity groups (do not need to win, unlocked immediately)
>
> Hybrid Affinity - Supremacy/Harmony: Start the game with one random
>   Wonder already built and your starship repair costs are reduced by
>   50%.
>
> Hybrid Affinity - Supremacy/Purity: Start the game with one
>   random Wonder already built and receive doubled resources from
>   completing missions.
>
> Hybrid Affinity - Purity/Harmony: Receive doubled
>   resources from completing missions and your starship repair costs are
>   reduced by 50%.
>
> Hybrid Affinity - Purity/Supremacy: Receive doubled
>   resources from completing missions and start the game with one random
>   Wonder already built.
>
> Hybrid Affinity - Harmony/Supremacy: Your
>   starship repair costs are reduced by 50% and start the game with one
>   random Wonder already built.
>
> Hybrid Affinity - Harmony/Purity: Your
>   starship repair costs are reduced by 50% and receive doubled resources
>   from completing missions.
>
> **Mission Unlocks**
>
> Mission - New Jerusalem: Protect the religious refugees. Unlocked by completing the Quest "FOUND AN OUTPOST."
>
> Mission - Assembly Required: Protect the
>   cargo transports. Unlocked by completing the Quest "GIFTS FROM HOME."
>
> Mission - The Arena: Battle without shields. Unlocked by completing
>   the Quest "HOSTILE TAKEOVER."

*Note that the hybrid affinities are listed requiring 3 points in the second affinity, but some sources suggest it has to be 4

What Starships can unlock in Beyond Earth. Note that these are all 'loadout' options when starting a game, and the new maps appear under Advanced Worlds. Aside from maps, they are unlocked by completing missions in Starships. Taken from [this forum thread](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showpost.php?p=13731107&postcount=6). Note that I have added Glacial Map and updated Tiny Islands per [this page](http://blog.gameagent.com/civilization-beyond-earth-how-to-use-my2k/).

> **Map - Glacial Map**
>
> Bonus: new map type
>
> Unlocked By: Login to My2k
>
> **Map - Tiny Islands**
>
> Bonus: new map type
>
> Unlocked By: winning a a Population victory
>
> **Map - Inland Sea**
>
> Bonus: new map type
>
> Unlocked By: winning a Domination victory
>
> **Colonist - Pioneers**
>
> Bonus: build colonists and explorers twice as fast
>
> Unlocked By: completing the "Fleet Escape" mission
>
> **Colonist - Mercenaries**
>
> Bonus: all cities have +25 HP and all units have +10% combat and
>   ranged strength in friendly territory
>
> Unlocked By: completing the "Dark Star" mission
>
> **Spacecraft - Supply Module**
>
> Bonus: begin with 2 resource pods near your first city
>
> Unlocked By: completing "Den of Thieves!" mission (Pirate homeworld)
>
> **Spacecraft - Electromagnetic Sensor**
>
> Bonus: reveal Artifacts on map
>
> Unlocked By: completing the "Final Justice!" mission (Marauder
>   homeworld)
>
> **Cargo - Cryotome**
>
> Bonus: begin with a free virtue
>
> Unlocked By: completing the "Fragile" mission
>
> **Cargo - Xeno Management**
>
> Bonus: begin with an Ultrasonic Emitter unit (does 10 damage to all
>   adjacent aliens)
>
> Unlocked By: completing the "Death Craft Alpha" quest